# Flux BufferedInputStream

Tags: java, android, inputstream, bufferedinputstream

I have been on this problem for more than two weeks. i have a music player which supports song lyrics in lrc format. when I start playing a song, the lyrics are displayed correctly and without problem but when I click on next and the next song is playing normally these lyrics should also be displayed but it is not the case. those are always the lyrics of the previous song that appear. How do I clear the old BufferedInputStream from the display so that the new one is displayed? NB: note that the LRC lyrics file is read via a BufferedInputStream. Help please svppppp !!! thank you in advance